# Spring Data Repositories - Find where field in list

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-commons

I'm trying to use spring `PagingAndSortingRepository` with a `find MyEntity where field in fieldValues` query as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntity extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, String> {

    List<MyEntity> findByMyField(Set<String> myField);

}
```

But of no success.

I expected the above function to return all entities whose field matches one of the field values but it only returns **empty results**.

Even though it seems like a pretty straight forward ability i could not find any reference to it in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html).

Is / How that could be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: I want to search by a list and a string , i.e my mehtod has 2 paramemeters a list and a string , will it work ? , If yes how shall I name my method

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should indeed be possible if you are searching on a specific field within your entity and you want to return a list of all that field matches at least one entry in some collection. The documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.x/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters) says this can be achieved using the keyword `In` example: `findByAgeIn(Collection<Age> ages)` and is equivalent to `… where x.age in ?1`

From your post i'm not 100% sure if this is the use case you are after but give this a try. You will need to search on a specific field, so replace 'field' with whatever field you are searching on. If you are searching on multiple fields it may be possible to concatenate the results with the `Or` keyword and specify multiple fields that way.

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntity extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, String> {

    List<MyEntity> findByFieldIn(Set<String> myField);

}
```

Answer (score 6):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Your method name has to be `findByMyFieldIn` so you got to add an `In` at the end to get a `where ... in (..)` query.