# Spring JPA find entity where property containing List

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**For example:**

This is the name property of an object I want to search for:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit`

When I fill in "lo adip tetur" (lo (= Lorem), dipi (=adipiscing), tetur (=consectetur)  ) I want to be able to find this object.

I tried to split my name property on space and pass it to the jpa method but I did not get any results.

`List<Obj> findAllByNameIgnoreCaseContaining(String[] splittedName);`

What would be the correct way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837725/spring-data-repositories-find-where-field-in-list

Comment: I'm afraid that the linked answer from @Ajay Kumar might fall short when it comes to text fragment search, since for example 'in' and 'like' cannot be combined

Comment: You're right fladdimir that indeed will be a problem for my use case. Thank you for the suggestion AjayKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex query will allow you to specify this type of complex text search criteria.
Regular expressions are supported by many databases, and can be supplied when using a native query.

An example for [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) could look like this:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value =
  "SELECT * FROM my_entity
   WHERE text_column ~ :contentRegex")
List<MyEntity> findByContentRegex(@Param("contentRegex") String contentRegex);
```

To match the first two characters of the first three words, you could for example pass a regex like this one:

```
var result = repository.findByContentRegex("^Lo\S*\sip\S*\sdo.*");
```

(a string starting with `Lo`, followed by an arbitrary number of non-whitespace characters, a whitespace character, `ip`, an arbitrary number of non-whitespace characters, a whitespace character, `do`, and an arbitrary number of arbitrary characters)

Of course you can dynamically assemble the regex, e.g. by concatenating user-supplied search term fragments:

```
List<String> searchTerms = List.of("Lo", "ip", "do"); // e.g. from http request url params
String regex = "^"+String.join("\S*\s", searchTerms) + ".*";
var result = repository.findByContentRegex(regex);
```

See e.g. https://regex101.com/ for an interactive playground.

---

Note that complex expressions may cause the query to become expensive, so that one may consider more advanced approaches at some point, like e.g. *full text search* which can make use of special indexing. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-intro.html
Also note that [setting a query timeout is recommended](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) for potentially hostile parameter sources.
Apart from that, there are also more specialized search servers e.g. like [apache-solr](https://solr.apache.org/features.html#top).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! My regex looks something like this and it seems to be working:

for (String term : searchTerms) {
      regex.append(String.format("(?=.*%s.*)", escapeSpecialRegexChars(term)));
 }